# Unresolved Reference when use Java Constants

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

When i tried to build, ide throw error: "Unresolved reference: X "

X is any Java constant (public static final) on (public) class Java

Can’t use:

```
android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS
Build.VERSION_CODES.M
Etc
```

I have tried:

```
Invalidate Cache in Android Studio
gradlew cleanBuildCache
Clean / Rebuild
Clone project on other folder,
Etc
```

It’s a mixed project, Java & Kotlin

I can use static methods, like:

```
public static Uri getUriForFile from public class FileProvider
Etc
```

Error line:

```
10:38:23.053 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Task] e: C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyAndroidProject\app\src\main\kotlin\com\myapp\mypackage\android\PermissionsHelper.kt: (67, 66): Unresolved reference: M
```

I’m using:

Gradle Configuration

```
ext.kotlin_version = ‘1.3.10’
classpath ‘com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1’
androidExtensions { experimental = true }
```

Software

```
Windows 10 Pro 10.0.17134 N/D Compilation 17134 x64

Android Studio 3.2.1 Build #Al-181-5540.7.32.5056338,build on Octubre 8, 2018

java version “1.8.0_162”
Java™ SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot™ 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
```

Stacktrace:

```
10:38:23.076 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
10:38:23.076 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:38:23.076 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
10:38:23.076 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
10:38:23.076 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Compilation error. See log for more details
10:38:23.076 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:38:23.076 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
10:38:23.076 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  Run with --scan to get full insights.
10:38:23.076 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:38:23.076 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
10:38:23.077 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
10:38:23.077 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
10:38:23.077 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
10:38:23.077 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
10:38:23.077 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipCachedTaskExecuter.execute(SkipCachedTaskExecuter.java:103)
10:38:23.077 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
10:38:23.077 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
10:38:23.077 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.execute(ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.java:66)
10:38:23.077 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
10:38:23.077 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
10:38:23.077 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter
```

Comment: Please show how exactly you're referencing the constant.

Comment: Even in annotations, @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M), or just: val documents = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS

Comment: Are the classes where the constants are defined imported?

Comment: Try File -> Sync Project with Gradle File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you **@yole** and **@Rod_Algonquin** for the help, meanwhile i was writing the questions, and answering the questions, the [Rubber duck method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) help me, the IDE was throwing me a error "Unresolved reference", but the problem was the annotation:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
```

Because: `minSdkVersion 16`

I was working on **PermissionsHelper.kt**, I was using *Activity* instead of *android.support.v4.app.Fragment* or *ContextCompat* for old versions.

Sorry guys for not post the code, and the complete gradle, i wanted to do a short post, this is my fist post.

Thank yo for all the help.